.NET 8: "System.Management currently is only supported for Windows desktop applications" when using WMI and target runtime "winx64"
We are getting this runtime error since we switched the target runtime for the publish process of our WinForms application from "portable" to "winx64" and when we use WMI functions, e. g.
var mo = new ManagementObject
{
    Path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", root))
};

Switching back to portable solves the problem. Why is that?
The csproj contains
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>

and
<PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="8.0.0" />

The .pubxml:
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>SQL01</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>\\192.168.4.14\public\November\Publish</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>


What are the actual settings? What does the csproj file contain? .NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a cross platform runtime that can't call OS-specific functions. There's no "portable" in .NET Core. There are runtime identifiers if you want to use OS-specific functionality. For Windows there's win and win-x64

@Panagiotis Kanavos: Umm, I don't get it - why is the error saying "is only supported for Windows" when we DO use win(-x64) for the publish?

Hi could you share more detail about your csproj file and pubxml file as I'm unable to repro the issue that you encountered?Your issue could be caused by improperly import the System.Management NuGet package but more information would be appreciated.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
